# Cannot test my model tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rake, bundler

I have tests in the folder:

```
 test/models/person/helper/age_calculator_test.rb
```

These test should fail because of:

```
  assert_equal false, true
```

they do fail when I run:

```
bundle exec m test/models/person/helper/age_calculator_test.rb
```

But when Im running:

```
bundle exec m test/models
```

**These Tests are not run!** What do I wrong? 
How can I test all of my **Model-Test** with Bundler in one command? Thanks!!

Comment: What happens when they do not run?  Do you get a message of some kind?  An error message?  Please share!

Comment: No It seems like this test are simply not acessed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you use the [Metal test runner](https://github.com/qrush/m). I cannot see anywhere on its documentation supporting path testing such as `test/models`. Its main feature is to run tests by line number.

If you would like to execute all of your model tests you could use Rails'

```
rake test:models
```

to do it. See the RoR Guide on [Rake Tasks for Running your Tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests) for more options.